# Octave gets stuck on Busy... inside TeXmacs in Windows OS

Tags: octave, texmacs

I have TeXmacs and Octave installed, both working properly otherwise. I have also added the path to `octave` executable (i.e. `C:\Octave\Octave-5.1.0.0\mingw64\bin`) to the Windows environment variables and `octave` runs in cmd/PowerShell terminals and Jupyter with no hassle. However, when running Octave inside TeXmacs through `Toolbar > insert > session > octave` it gets stuck on `Busy...`, the same reaction for any other commands as well:

```
   
                     Octave gets stuk on Busy... inside TeXmacs.
```

This is my environment:

- TeXmacs 1.99.9
- Octave 5.1.0 (installed through Chocolatey)
- Windows 10 version 1809

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

**P.S.** I have reported [this issue](https://github.com/texmacs/plugins/issues/11) in the TeXmacs repo.

Comment: I don't know whether this question is on topic in SO, or specifically, whether TeXmacs is considered as a software tool commonly used by programmers. For the moment there is no SE for TeXmacs. However, there is [a proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121978/texmacs) in Area51. You can join and ask there.

Comment: I do follow that proposal. But for the moment I don't know any better place to ask this question ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It seems that octave does not send back to texmacs the message to close output and so things get stuck since texmacs is still waiting for them while maybe octave is waiting already for input. I tried on mac and is the same problem. Maybe something changed in the last versions of the program, you should fiddle a bit around and see what happened.

Comment: Recently, I'm developing on the octave plugin.

Comment: I think it has been fixed in GNU TeXmacs 2.1.1

Answer (score 3):

@Foad. I wrote an updated Octave plugin for Texmacs. I tried it on Windows, OSX and Linux, works on the systems I have access to. If you are interested to test it, you can download the zipped archive from here https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/texmacs-dev/2019-12/msg00005.html.

To install it, unzip the archive and copy the octaveX directory in the application plugins folder, alongside all the plugins that come with the standard Texmacs installation. Won’t work if installed in  ~/.Texmacs/plugins. If everything goes fine, you should find a new Insert/Session/OctaveX menu (note: I changed the session name). If not, try to refresh the plugin system with the menu Tools/Update/Plugins.  If you try it, please let me know, especially if you find troubles. In case I will do my best to fix them.

A *fundamental* prerequisite is a working octave-cli command in a operating system shell. Should be standard on Linux, may require some additional setup on Windows (environmental variables) or OSX (.bash_profile). You can find some help and more details under the menu Help/Plug-ins/OctaveX.

Concerning the error you found, as far I understand there are some issues with the standard distributed plugin: first, a .octaverc file is missing, so several variables are not initialized, in addition the Windows version calls a not existent file. Moreover the plotting functions are quite old and are not compatibile with Octave newer than version 2 (or maybe 3, anyway a quite old version).

Answer (score 2):

You could try to run the command in

```
%TEXMACS_PATH%/plugins/octave/bin/tm_octave.bat
```

from the terminal to see what happens. There is a problem with this plugin and it does not work also on Mac but I do not know enough Octave to fix it. Somehow it does not manage to find the files which are in

```
%TEXMACS_PATH%/plugins/octave/octave
```

Please try to modify tm-start.m to look like

```
d=getenv("TEXMACS_PATH");
if (length(d) > 0)
    addpath("tm:polynomial:plot")
    tmrepl
endif
```

Comment: great. I'm happy to see you are going across different social media and answer different questions. hopefully Twitter will be the next 

Comment: Please try to modify tm-start.m to look like
```
d=getenv("TEXMACS_PATH");
if (length(d) > 0)
    addpath("tm:polynomial:plot")
    tmrepl
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows, octave should be run using the scripts octave.bat (in the mingw64\bin directory of the octave install) or octave.vbs (in the install directory) for the GUI

You should not run octave.exe directly.

Comment: Thanks but you actually did not answer my question. I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

Comment: @Foad Why is your question not answered with this? Don't use the exe directly, use the .vbs

Comment: Dear @Andy are you able to run Octave inside the TeXmacs using the above instructions? See, I'm not running the `Octave.exe` at all and the only reason I mentioned it in the question was to show that the binary folder is added to the environment variables and known to the OS. Besides, I should mention that Octave works fine on Jupyter, so there should be some other issue. Unless I'm missing something here?

Comment: You said "I have also added the path to octave executable (i.e. C:\Octave\Octave-5.1.0.0\mingw64\bin)", so what exactly is TeXmacs running ? It should be octave.bat

Comment: @lostbard That I'm not sure. The plugin for calling Octave can be seen [here](https://github.com/texmacs/plugins/tree/master/octave) I'm not sure which file it is calling to.